# trying to stop jQuery from firing table tr onclick event if I click a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've got a table which has a checkbox in each row. I made an event handler for the  click to move to another page, but I want to stop it from moving if I've clicked the checkbox. The following code is what I have:

**Table layout**

```
echo '<tr class="unread"><td><label class="fancy-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><span>&nbsp;</span></label></td>';
echo '<td><span class="from">' . $message['message_from_first_name'] . '</span></td>';
echo '<td><span class="title">' . $message['subject'] . '</span> <span class="preview">- ' . strip_tags($message['message_preview']) . '</span></td>';
echo '<td><span class="timestamp">' . $message['datestamp'] . '</span></td>';
echo '<td style="display:none;">' . $message['message_id'] . '</td>';
echo'</tr>';
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>

    $('table tr').click(function(event) {

        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {


            var id = $("td:last-child", this).text();
            $.redirect('?action=view-message', {message_id: id});

        }

   });

</script>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this doesn't work. The redirect still fires!

Comment: Could you show the actual generated HTML and not the PHP script code. Also, just so you are aware, echoing HTML like this is really ill advised. You should look into PHP's templating capabilities instead.

Comment: Try `event.stopPropagation()` to stop triggering other element's events.

Comment: I have a feeling your CSS is hiding your checkbox and you click on a label. `console.log(event.target)` shows what?

Comment: console.log shows <span>::before"&nbsp;"</span>

Comment: Adam - the event.stopPropogation() doesn't work.

Comment: TIG - html generated code is this (will look into PHP templating thanks!!)

<td><label class="fancy-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><span>&nbsp;</span></label></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should work exactly the way it is written, but the classes on the label and the layout suggest to be the checkbox is NOT what you are checking on so the if check is going to fail.

So the event is either going to be the label or the span, not the input.

```
if ( !$(event.target).closest(".fancy-checkbox").length) {
```

Comment: I tried this just now and no change. It still console logs the span, and I've uncommented the redirect lines and still getting the same result :-(

Comment: AHHH stupid me...I had .type in there! Should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( 'table tr input[type="checkbox"]' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
} );
```

After that you can bind click at your `table tr`, because checkbox click will stop after firing

Comment: Should not be needed.

Comment: @epascarello "Should not be needed" what?

Comment: Because the OPs code runs correct as it is. There is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting `if` condition to `event.target.type !== 'checkbox' && event.target.tagName !== "label"`

```js
$('table tr').click(function(event) {
  console.log("checbox")
  if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox' && event.target.tagName !== "label") {
    console.log(event.target)
      // var id = $("td:last-child", this).text();
      // $.redirect('?action=view-message', {
      //   message_id: id
      // });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="checkbox" /></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the event is still firing because the checkbox is inside a table tr.

Rather assign the following onclick event to the checkbox:

```
onclick="event.cancelBubble = true;
         if (event.stopPropagation) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         }"
```

Or you could add the above to a function. Let's call it "stopevent" for this example.

```
function stopevent() {
         event.cancelBubble = true;
         if (event.stopPropagation) {
           event.stopPropagation();
         }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="stopevent()">
```

We could either include the function within script tags or use a javascript file included in the page, also in script tags, but using a the src attribute for the file location.

Example of external file named functions in our assets/js/ folder of the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/functions.js">
```

Or on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function stopevent() {
           event.cancelBubble = true;
           if (event.stopPropagation) {
             event.stopPropagation();
           }
  }
</script>
```